# CKEditor, Jquery - find and replace HTML

Tags: jquery, ckeditor

I am totally new to CKEditor, hence please bear with my stupid questions. I have a CMS that uses CKEditor to enter articles into a DB. I have been asked to write a plugin to the editor to do a particular task which is as follows:

I have an image in the editor. When I click on the image to select it and click on a button that I coded it gets me the image html like <img src="imageurl" border="0" />. Now I need to find out if the image tag is wrapped with furthermore html like:

```
<div class="photo">
    <p class="inner">
        <img src="imageurl" border="0" /><span>some text here</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

if yes, I need to be able to edit the text in the span tag and be able to add inline style to DIV or P, if not I need to wrap <img src="imageurl" border="0" /> with :

```
<div class="photo">
    <p class="inner">
        <img src="imageurl" border="0" /><span>some text here</span>
    </p>
</div>
```

P.S. I can sit thru and may be come up with a solution if I has sometime. But my deadline is too close!

Could someone please please help me with this? Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
R

Comment: Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the Jquery function [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get the "higher levels" in your html structure starting from `<img />`